# How to apply solid colors to data bar in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, colors, bar-chart

My data bar looks good (solid) when executing the VBA command. However, after I saved the file and reopened, data bar changed to gradient automatically. How do I avoid this?

Before saving and reopening file:

[image: Before saving the file]

After saving and reopening file:

[image: After saving the file]

Here's the code I used:

```
Dim DB As Databar
Set DB = Range("K2:K10").FormatConditions.AddDatabar

With DB
    .BarFillType = xlDataBarSolid
    .BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderSolid
    With .BarBorder.Color
        .Color = 15698432
    End With
    With .BarColor
        .Color = 15698432
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End With

With DB.BarColor
    .Color = 15698432
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

With Range("K2:K10").FormatConditions(1)
    .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
    .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax
End With
```

Comment: If the vba code runs successfully, I don't believe this is an issue with VBA.  I have made a suggested edit to add the `excel` and `bar-chart` tags to see if you can get more help on the issue from a more broad base of excel users.  However, again, it doesn't appear to be a VBA issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have this twice; either one will suffice.

```
...
    With .BarColor
        .Color = 15698432
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End With

With DB.BarColor
    .Color = 15698432
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
...
```

Also, and this is VERY IMPORTANT: In my experience, once you've difined a Databar--you are done with the fill, and it will not change. If needed, you can delete the Databar and set it up again:

```
With Range("K2:K10")
    For i = .FormatConditions.Count To 1 Step -1
            .FormatConditions(i).Delete
    Next
    'Create a DataBar object ' as you've been doing it already
    ...
End With
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have created test Sub, placed in Sheet1 VBA code module and ran it in Excel 2010 (see the code snippet below). Everything works fine as expected.

```
Sub FormatDatabar()
    Dim DB As Databar
    Set DB = Range("K2:K10").FormatConditions.AddDatabar

    With DB
        .BarFillType = xlDataBarSolid
        .BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderSolid
        With .BarBorder.Color
            .Color = 15698432
        End With
        With .BarColor
            .Color = 15698432
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With

    'this is redundant
    'With DB.BarColor
        '.Color = 15698432
        '.TintAndShade = 0
    'End With

    With Range("K2:K10").FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax
    End With
End Sub
```

It also works well with Hex color index:

```
Sub FormatDatabar()
    Dim DB As Databar
    Set DB = Range("K2:K10").FormatConditions.AddDatabar

    With DB
        .BarFillType = xlDataBarSolid
        .BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderSolid
        With .BarBorder.Color
            'Green color
            .Color = &HC0F0&
        End With
        With .BarColor
            .Color = &HC0F0&
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With

    With Range("K2:K10").FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax
    End With
End Sub
```

You probably should check the settings on your machine. Kind regards,