# How to make a whole worksheet use solid fill in the data bars in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem with my excel 2010 (and 2013 also) that I have a page
worksheet with data bars, and I have set them to solid fill, but every time
I close and open the document, it has changed to gradient again, quite annoying (since you can't really see the progress when it is fading into white, which is the same as the background...)

Checked the Office Homepage, but couldn't find this issue anywhere mentioned.
Also tried to Google it, just found a few who had similar problem, but no solution.

For the purpose of presentation I could change the background etc. But what is the fun in that, I would like to try to make sure it is solid fill every time I open this file. And it looks nice when it is solid fill.

I see 2 ways this could be achieved:

1. Would be if one could change the default settings (since I guess that is what happens every time I re-open the file). Tried to Google it but couldn't find it.
2. Another way would be to have a VBA script that says "hey, all you data bars in this range, you should have solid bars".

I tried option 2 on my own, but since I'm quite new to scripting in VBA, I didn't succeed, but it looked like this my try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 dad = Range("A1:Z100")
 Dim b As Databar
 b = dad.FormatCondition.AddDatabar
 b.BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid

End Sub
```

But that didn't work, I guess one should create the bars and then use this options on those bars, but I already have a document with maybe 200 bars, which looks perfectly fine, except for them loosing the solid option.
And since they depend on different numbers (the data bars), I can't have one "rule to rule them all" (conditioning formatting).

**Update: 2015-05-22**

Managed to create new Databars to my liking, by this code below

```html
Sub TestDatabars()

    ' column B real values
    Dim B1rv As Databar
    Range("B6:B10, B14:B37,B42:B43").Select
    ' remove old settings (gradient fill)
    With Selection
        .FormatConditions(1).Delete
    End With
    ' add a new one
    Set B1rv = Selection.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    
    With B1rv
        .BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid
    End With
    With B1rv.BarColor
        .Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    End With
    
    B1rv.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=0
    B1rv.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=Range("B1")

end sub
```

But I guess the question remains if I need to change all my old databars (around 100 databars) or if there is a more common way.

Will test some thing with making a range selection and see if I get edit those allready there.

Comment: In what way did your code not work? Do you get an error? Does it execute but not change anything?

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608334/how-to-apply-solid-colors-to-data-bar-in-excel-vba) is the 3rd answer for a Google search for `excel vba databar`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27609458/2344413) to that question looks like it includes some important details for you.

Comment: Hi FreeMan, thank you for your quick answer, I might have been a bit vague in my problem description.

My problem is that the data bars I got are based on cell values, therefore I would not really like to make new bars, just to use the bars allready there, and make them solid fill, instead of the gradient fill which always come back to me. When I close and open the file again.
So basically I would just like the existing bars to be solid, and not create new data bars, are that possibly ?

Comment: To be honest, I've not used the databars, I just searched, and that's what I found. There are two answers to that question, but neither was tagged as having solved the issue. I'd take a look at both the suggestions on the question I linked and see if that will help you any. If not, hopefully, someone will come along who knows more about them than I do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set b = dad.FormatCondition.AddDatabar
```

Notice the keyword `Set` - you need to use that when assigning an object.